# Manipulation of data to form suitable for contour plotting

Tags: r, list, data-structures, contour

I am looking to plot binned data as a function of a variable in the form a contour plot, however since I am still not used to the way R handles data structures I am struggling to coerce my data into a form ready for plotting. I suspect the simplest format to have my data in (for example if using lattice) would be a dataframe in the form:

```
X1  Z1  Y1
X2  Z2  Y2
X3  Z3  Y3
X4  Z4  Y4
Xn  Zn  Yn
```

Currently I have data in the form:

```
x <- as.numeric(c(-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,15,20,30))
y <- head(logspace(-3.6,-1.7,15),-1) + diff(logspace(-3.6,-1.7,15))
z <- list(c(seq.int(30,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(35,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(40,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(45,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(50,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(60,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(55,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(50,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(40,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(30,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(20,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(10,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(10,1,length.out=15)),c(seq.int(10,1,length.out=15)))
names(z) <- paste("x", 1:14, sep = "")
```

Thus you will see I have two numeric dataforms (the x and y dimensions) and my z values in a list which is the same length as y. The list contains numeric dataforms which are the same length as x. For example:

```
length(x)
[1] 15
length(y)
[1] 14
length(z)
[1] 14
length(z$x1)
[1] 15
```

So my very basic question is what would be the best approach to coerce this data to a form suitable (perhaps to a dataframe called "mydata"?) such that a command such as:

```
require(lattice)
contourplot(z ~ x * y, data = mydata)
```

would generate a plot?

Comment: You don't have enough `z` values. You need a value for each grid location, so you need `length(x) *length(y)` values to be able to plot.  Once you get the correct data values set up, you can either use the `formula` method for `contourplot` or make `z` into a matrix and define the `row.values` and `column.values` as `x` and `y` .

Comment: Hi carl, thanks for the comment but I am still rather confused- to my eye the dimensions are correct- I have 15 x-values, 14 y-values and z is a list of 14 lists each of which has 15 values. In a sense I could plot this by hand so in what way do I not have a value for each grid location?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear what your `z` contained.  I believe `newz<-matrix(unlist(z),nrow=length(y))` (or possibly `nrow=length(x)`) will give you a matrix `newz` which can be plotted against your `x` and `y` values.

Answer (score 0):

z is in a wrong format. The easiest way is to make a data.frame containing one row for each observation.

```
my.data.frame <- expand.grid(x = 1:15, y = 1:14)
my.data.frame$z <- with(my.data.frame, x ^2 + x + x * y + y ^ 2 + y)
library(lattice)
contourplot(z ~ x * y, data = my.data.frame)
```